# Can't put width in percentage

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has white background. I have put his width in % so it fits on all screens. But the problem is when I give the height a % it just dissapears and when I give it px it works fine.

How do I fix this?

CSS:

```
.middentextvak
{

    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 43%;
    height: 500px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 7%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5LmF/8/
I don't know why it appears white the whole page but at a normal browser it's showing correct.

Comment: You mean `height` or `width`? Because only, `width` is in percentage in your code.

Comment: Can you show your HTML too please. What is the height of the parent element?

Comment: It depend on relative back object, What is back object size?

Comment: Make sure the container of your element has some height set.

Comment: hold on guys I'm making the jfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have set the `body` and `html`. Below is a working example of height and width set in %

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/SqX5f/2/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To put height in %, you have to fix a height for the html and body.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```